# How would I make a webpage randomly generate a new video every time it is refreshed using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, video

Ok, so I want to randomly generate a selected group of videos every time the webpage is refreshed, or after clicking a certain button, using Javascript. I was able to do this with words but cannot do it with videos. For example, when the page first loads, video 3 will load, the after refreshing or hitting button, video 2, then video 4, video 1, and so on. I have selected 3 videos I want to do this with (more will be added later), https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rz5TGN7eUcM, and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMNry4PE93Y. Any help with what the HTML and Javascript coding should look like? Thanks.

Comment: how do you do it with words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your videos in an array

```
var myVideos = ['link1', 'link2', 'link3'];
```

Then get a random video:

```
var randomVideo = myVideos[Math.floor(Math.random() * myVideos.length)];
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but what would the html code look like. currently i have it as <video id="randomvideo">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video> and the javascript code as <script>
   var myvideos = ["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rz5TGN7eUcM", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMNry4PE93Y", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7RgN9ijwE4"];
   var randomvideo = myVideos[Math.floor(Math.random() * myvideos.length)];
</script>

Comment: I'd use JavaScript's document.write() to write the HTML for you. So in your JS include something like:
`document.write('<video id="randomvideo"> <source src="' + randomVideo + '" type="video/mp4" /> </video>');`